# ASCII to EBCDIC Character Incoding

Tags: java, character-encoding, hex, ascii, ebcdic

While converting ASCII String to EBCDIC:

```
System.out.println(new String("0810C2200000820000000400000000000000052852304131419391011590620022300270".getBytes("UTF-8"), "CP1047"));
```

I am getting below as output String:

```
ä??????
```

But, what I want is:

```
F0 F8    F1 F0    C2 20    00 00    82 00    00 00    04 00  00 00    00 00    00 00   F4 F1    F0 F1    F1 F5  F9 F0    F6 F2    F0 F0    F2 F2    F3 F0    F0 F2    F7 F0
```

How I can achieve it? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: is the formatting important? or do you want to output the bytes as text encoded in cp1047?

Comment: You're decoding *from* CP1047 *to* UTF-16 with this code. The result of converting to EBCDIC is a byte array, not a String.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert the string this way

```
String string = "0810C220";
byte[] bytes = string.getBytes("CP1047");
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%s %X%n", string.charAt(i), bytes[i]);
}
```

But your example seems to be wrong.

following are correct, one character from input string is converted to the related EBCDIC code

```
0 F0
8 F8
1 F1
0 F0
```

here your example is wrong, because your example treats `C2` and `20` as two characters in the input string but not as two characters in the EBCDIC code

```
C C3
2 F2
2 F2
0 F0
```

For the conversion in the other direction you could do it that way

```
// string with hexadecimal EBCDIC codes
String sb = "F0F8F1F0";
int countOfHexValues = sb.length() / 2;
byte[] bytes = new byte[countOfHexValues];
for(int i = 0; i < countOfHexValues; i++) {
    int hexValueIndex = i * 2;
    // take one hexadecimal string value
    String hexValue = sb.substring(hexValueIndex, hexValueIndex + 2);
    // convert it to a byte
    bytes[i] = (byte) (Integer.parseInt(hexValue, 16) & 0xFF);
}
// constructs a String by decoding bytes as EBCDIC
String string = new String(bytes, "CP1047");
```

Comment: How Can I achieve reverse of it, means from a String str="F0F8F1F0" to 0810?

Comment: Thank you, it's of great help!!

Comment: I am facing another issue with conversion from hex to ascii, that is it is giving me corrupt data for some hex values, might be for postive hex. can you please tell me how can I fix it?

Comment: like this : 000086^Ìb*

Comment: What have you tried? What is the hex string you want to convert into ASCII?

Comment: If you want to convert EBCDIC (as hex code string. e.g. "F0F1F0F0767F46") into ASCII you should use `new String(bytes, "ASCII")` instead of `new String(bytes, "CP1047")`. As you might know what the EBCDIC is look it have a look at the convertion page in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_1047) to find the right character translation.